# How to send an email to sharepoint o365 file owners using python

Tags: python, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am new to python, and need some suggestions.
I have a sharepoint 365 folder with multiple files.
Each file got a different owner.
I want to send email to each file owner with the sharepoint file link automatically using python.

Please advise which library or API i can use.
Would appreciate some simple examples on usage.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have used:

```python
import os
import smtplib
import email.mime.multipart as MIMEMultipart
import email.mime.text as MIMEText
import email.mime.base as MIMEBase
from email import encoders

smtp_server = ''
smtp_server_port = 25
origin_server = 'localhost'

def sendMail(from_address, to_address, msg_subject, mail_body, attachment_location):
    msg = MIMEMultipart.MIMEMultipart()
    msg.update({'From': from_address, 'To': to_address, 'Subject': msg_subject})
    msg.attach(MIMEText.MIMEText(mail_body, 'plain'))

    file_attachment = MIMEBase.MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    with open(attachment_location, "rb") as file_data:
        file_attachment.set_payload(file_data.read())
    encoders.encode_base64(file_attachment)
    file_attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition',
                               f'attachment; filename={os.path.basename(attachment_location)}')
    msg.attach(file_attachment)

    transfer_agent = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_server_port, origin_server)
    transfer_agent.sendmail(from_address, to_address, msg.as_string())
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint has a built-in rest api endpoint that could send emails to SP user.

```
/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail
```

> Check https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/send-email-notification-through-rest-api-in-sharepoint-2013/

Since you're using Python, I would suggest following library:

- [Office365-REST-Python-Client](https://pypi.org/project/Office365-REST-Python-Client/)

And please take a reference below demo:

- https://github.com/kongmengfei/sharedproject/blob/master/PythonConsole-uploadfileSPO/PythonApplication2/SendEmail.py

BR